# Migrating AndroidX run error android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: java, android, mobile, migration, androidx

I just have migrated my project to AndroidX. Sync and build phase are ok, but when I try to run the compiler show me this error:

```
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
```

This error raises on a builded file

```
// Generated code from Butter Knife. Do not modify!
package com.xdatanet.cda.Adapters;

import android.support.annotation.CallSuper; //<-- Doesn't exists
import android.support.annotation.UiThread; //<-- Doesn't exists
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import butterknife.Unbinder;
import butterknife.internal.Utils;
import com.xdatanet.cda.CustomView.CDATextView;
import com.xdatanet.cda.R;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.lang.Override;

public class CommunicationAdapter$CommunicationViewHolder_ViewBinding implements Unbinder {
  private CommunicationAdapter.CommunicationViewHolder target;

  @UiThread  //<-- First error
  public CommunicationAdapter$CommunicationViewHolder_ViewBinding(CommunicationAdapter.CommunicationViewHolder target,
      View source) {
      // Some generated code
  }

  @Override
  @CallSuper //<-- Second error
  public void unbind() {
      // Some generated code
  }
}
```

Gradle properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Butterknife implementation into gradle

```
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
```

The IDE says `Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited.`

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Min Sdk 19, Max Sdk 28
- Gradle version 3.2.1

It seems to be an error with butterknife but I don't know why.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest updating ButterKnife to the newest version.

I haven't migrated my projects to AndroidX yet, but from the commit history on the ButterKnife github page, it would seem like that the newest 9.0.x versions support AndroidX.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: After updating butterknife to 10.2.1 it solved my problem.

Comment: This worked for me too updated butterknife to 10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when migrating to androidx. this issue comes due to the Old Butter Knife library dependency.

if you are using butter knife then you should use at least butter knife version 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT or above.

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```